# Writing out complex things with the "defaults" command in Terminal

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, terminal, nsuserdefaults

My Cocoa app writes out some involved things to user defaults using `NSUserDefaults`.

For example, if I type

```
defaults read com.mycompany.myapp SomeDefaultKey
```

in the Terminal, I get this output:

```
(
        (
        "2013-09-13 08:50:09 +0000",
        1
    ),
        (
        "2013-09-13 09:07:54 +0000",
        1
    )
)
```

so it's an array of two-element arrays each containing a date and a boolean.

How can I use the `defaults` command to add a new date-boolean array to the outer array?

Answer (score 1):

You use the `-array-add` option to do this - see `man defaults`. For example:

```
defaults write com.mycompany.myapp SomeDefaultKey -array-add '("2013-09-13 08:50:09 +0000", 2)'
```

The added value is an array - the `(` & `)` - of two items - `"2013-09-13 08:50:09 +0000"` and `2`. The single quotes (`'`) surround the value and basically you can provide any value in the format `defaults` itself would display it.

Comment: You have missed the actual command out of your example. Which will not work as shown. The example starts with "write". Which is a command in it's self. (used to send messages to another user). As I am sure you know the code should be /usr/bin/defaults write com.mycompany.myapp SomeDefaultKey -array-add '("2013-09-13 08:50:09 +0000", 2)'. But as better heads than mine seem to think the syntax is correct I cannot do the edit. Which would help people unfamiliar with unix

Comment: @markhunte - Oops, cut'n'paste from Terminal error. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: no problem. Just annoying that my edit was rejected. go figure.